# YouTrack as a Help Desk

Tags: integration, email, youtrack

I try to use the Mail Integration as described here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/7.0/Use-YouTrack-as-a-Help-Desk.html

Emails received in the INBOX but as soon as I try fetching them, I end up with the following error:

```
Failed to apply command "Last message related emails "$from" "$to" to issue created from email from "$from"
unknown command: Last message related emails "$from"
```

I did everything exactly as in the documentation and checked it many times. Settings are given just like this.

If you guys have any ideas on the topic please let me know.
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: We've considered Youtrack as a helpdesk solution but it didn't worked out. Every user that creates a ticket has to be registered in the system which is limited by 10K accounts (far not enough) for standalone edition and the cost becomes insane. A question to JetBrains: is there a way to have "guest" accounts for helpdesk and "full" accounts for our teams? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

could you please check the Mailbox Integration settings, the 'Postprocessing' tab in the mailbox rule? Please check that the command syntax is correct there (brackets included). It should read as follows:

`Last message related emails ${from} ${to} ${cc}`

Thank you!

Comment: yeah this is exactly what I added there, see screenshot attached in my posting

Comment: Could you also check that the field 'Last message related emails' is attached to the project Helpdesk?

Comment: yep that is also the case

Comment: Then pleasen submit a request into our support system: https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66282

Comment: and add the screeenshot of all the mailbox settings + the full logs of your instance. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YouTrack 2019.1
This was working for a long time with:
Last message related emails ${from} ${to} ${cc}
and then just stopped working (no updates applied).
After much frustration and nearly telling people we should scrap YouTrack, I wrapped the commands parameters in quotations and everything worked again.
Last message related emails "${from} ${to} ${cc}"